# How to perform conditional join more efficiently in Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a reasonably large dataframe on hand. Joining it with itself takes some time. But I want to join them with some conditions, which could make the resulting dataframe much smaller. My question is how can I take advantage of such conditions to make the conditional join faster to plain full join?

Code below for illustration:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

# example dataframe
rng = np.random.default_rng(1)

nrows = 3_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame(
    dict(
        day=rng.integers(1, 300, nrows),
        id=rng.integers(1, 5_000, nrows),
        id2=rng.integers(1, 5, nrows),
        value=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
    )
)

# joining df with itself takes around 10-15 seconds on a machine with 32 cores.
start = time.perf_counter()
df.join(df, on=["id", "id2"], how="left")
time.perf_counter() - start

# joining df with itself with extra conditions - the implementation below that takes very similar time (10-15 seconds).
start = time.perf_counter()
df.join(df, on=["id", "id2"], how="left").filter(
    (pl.col("day") < pl.col("day_right")) & (pl.col("day_right") - pl.col("day") <= 30)
)
time.perf_counter() - start
```

So, as mentioned above, my question is how can I take advantage of the conditions during join to make the 'conditional join' faster?

*It should be faster since the resulting dataframe after conditions has 10x less rows than the full join without any conditions.*

Comment: Hi @lebesgue, maybe it's related to this https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7247 ? do you have any performance improvements if you run the query in lazy mode?

Comment: I tried, but no improvement when using lazy mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With lazy and `streaming=True`, it is faster:

```py
In [5]: start = time.perf_counter()
   ...: df.lazy().join(df.lazy(), on=["id", "id2"], how="left").filter(
   ...:     (pl.col("day") < pl.col("day_right")) & (pl.col("day_right") - pl.col("day") <= 30)
   ...: ).collect()
   ...: time.perf_counter() - start
Out[5]: 11.083821532000002

In [6]: start = time.perf_counter()
   ...: df.lazy().join(df.lazy(), on=["id", "id2"], how="left").filter(
   ...:     (pl.col("day") < pl.col("day_right")) & (pl.col("day_right") - pl.col("day") <= 30)
   ...: ).collect(streaming=True)
   ...: time.perf_counter() - start
Out[6]: 7.110704054997768
```

Comment: what is the theory/logic behind this speedup? To me, streaming is more for memory efficiency.

Comment: If the tables are big, won't you run out of memory when collecting? How about e.g. sinking to a parquet file instead?